# How to interprete supervised ML algorithms (e.g. find subgroups with certain feature ranges)

Tags: machine-learning

For some ML cases it's important not only to give a reliable prediction but also explain this prediction.

If we talking about medical therapy efficiency prediction, physicians are curious to select some groups of patients which would have good or bad reaction.

**For example**: patients will react negatively for the therapy A in case they: 1) both high-weighted and have black hair; 2) both old-aged and were previously treated by therapy B; 3) both low-weighted and were previously treated by therapy C

It looks like clusterization inside classification.

What are common approaches for solving this task?

Answer (score -1):

I would say it looks like **"clustering on classified datas" (1)** or **"classification on clustered data" (2)**.

Where:
(1) would be: "What are main reason of reacting respectively negatively/pos?"
i.e. classify your data then run clustering on each class.
Then, for example, your result will be like "lot of negative patient are clustered together becuz they have black hair".

and (2) would be: "What will be the result of treatment (pos/neg) given a patient condition (high weighted, old etc...) 
i.e. cluster your data by condition, then run classification on each.
The result would be like "black hair people has 40% negative reaction"

this depend on what is important to you, you can see it a bit like conditionnal probability